# How to concat columns into a string in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, listagg

I have this table `Movie` with columns defined as `(CustomerId, MovieId, Name)` and I want to fetch these columns by concatenating them into a string in the position they are defined in Snowflake, by ordering through `ORDINAL_POSITION`.

So I found that using LISTAGG() get's me pretty close to what I want. By doing the following I get close to my desired string, but I get duplicates of the column names. I'm seeing that people will use `group by` and `order by` based on a column in the table instead of using ORDINAL_POSITION. So this is why I'm struggling to find a solution. I've found that `COALESCE` could help since it returns the first Non-Null value, however, I'm struggling to integrate this into my Query.

```
//Query
select listagg(column_name, ',') within group (order by ORDINAL_POSITION) 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name='Movie';
```

**Output:**

```
CUSTOMERID,CUSTOMERID,CUSTOMERID,MovieId,MovieId,MovieId,
Name,Name,Name
```

Any help or ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column names should be unqiue per table by design. Probably table exists in multiple schemas/databases:

```
select listagg(column_name, ',') within group (order by ORDINAL_POSITION) 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name='Movie'
  and table_schema = 'XXX'
  and table_catalog = 'YYY';
```

Comment: that was exactly it. thank you